# Best practice to create "flag" for multiprocess project with db as bridge between processes?

Tags: python, design-patterns, database-design

I have two processes: 1) **scraper** - take info from another website, do the needfull calculations and put results in db 2) web app (Flask) take data from db and draw plot with the help of matpotlib. The two processes do not communicate, but they use one db.

Problem: All works fine now, but to draw plots and save them to folder of web app project is time consuming operation, it takes about 5 seconds to display the page with plots. Pictures are created every time the webpage is requested, since data can be added to db in random moment and user should get plot with all information.

How I see the solution: To create table in db with only one line and only two colums: id = 1 and  boolean field in db. Let's call boolean column IS_UPDATED. When the **scraper** process put some new data to db, we change IS_UPDATED to True.  When the second process web app ask the data from db, it changes IS_UPDATED to False. Hereby the pictures are recreted only when new data was provided to db by the **scraper** process, otherwise we use the old pictures.

Is my solution is fine? Please share any other ways to do the same.

Comment: Is there anything keeping you from letting the scraper process do the drawing? That one seems to know precisely when a new plot needs to be drawn without the need for any synchronization.

Comment: @shmee it was made in webapp since we had some problems to run webapp in server and it was not clear what root to the the folder will be at the end, so initially the olot drawing was made in webapp and now I have what I have.

Comment: @shmee: I moved plotrawing to another process. Now I have the launcher process which start scrapper as subprocess every day after 7 a.m, if the scrapper is finished fine, the launcher start the plotdrawing subprocess and check if it is finished fine. The next day the launcher repeats all the steps. Flask webserver exists as separate process/app and apply to db and folder with pictures, if pictures are available, they are displayed, otherwise they are not displayed and user get only db info. Hereby pictures are always updated according lattest db info. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper

Comment: @barny thanks, I try to memorize it and write the word correctly next time. I am not native English speaker and wrote that text without translator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to implement a locking mechanism whereas DBMS already has its own. I.e. if App1 crashes between IS_UPDATED=True IS_UPDATED=False, the lock stays active.

A typical solution is based on transaction isolation levels. I suppose, App1 does the updates strongly in the scope of a single transaction, so if you set `REPEATABLE READ` or rather `SERILIZABLE` level, then App2 will always get the last **consistent** version of data.

Second point is the isolation implementation approach. When using a blocking DBMS, App2 will wait until App1 finishes whereas a version-based DBMS lets App2 read immediately last consistent data excluding App1 modifications which are not committed yet. I.e. SQL Server supports both approaches but requires some settings to do.

For more details have a look on "[Programming with databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2956300806)" book containing explanations and examples (first edition exists in Russian, too).

Comment: Well it is not locking mechanism, it was supposed more like some siganlling system whether process2 should create new pictures or go with old ones. Process2 request to db do not need to know end of transaction between Process1 and db.

Comment: I moved plotrawing to another process. Now I have the launcher process which start scrapper as subprocess after 7 a.m, if the scrapper is finished fine, the launcher start the plotdrawing subprocess and check if it is finished fine. Next day launcher repeats all the steps. Flask webserver exists as separate app and apply to db and folder with pictures, if pics are available, they are displayed, otherwise user get only db info. Hereby pics are always updated according lattest db info. Thank you very much, I'll look at the book, since I need to pick up some arhitecture skills somewhere